# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable when removing last 3 characters from string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe columns that I want to remove the last 3 characters from string: change '1996-09-27 00:00:00+10' to '1996-09-27 00:00:00'

I'm able to use `df['col'][0][:-3]` for a single string but received `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable` from `df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: x[:-3])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column is all strings, you can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['1996-09-27 00:00:00+10','1996-09-27 0000:00+11']})
df['col'].replace("[+][0-9]*","",regex=True)

0    1996-09-27 00:00:00
1    1996-09-27 00:00:00
```

My regex is not very good, but the part [+] search for a pattern that is a "+" sign followed by 0 or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason is because the column `col` includes both float and string values.

For example, if you have the dataframe bellow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['1996-09-27 00:00:00+10','1996-09-27 0000:00+11', 1000.5]})
```

Removing last 3 characters will raise an exception:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

The solution is to cast all values to string before applying string manipulations.

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str).apply(lambda l: l[:-3])
```

Answer (score 0):

I run the exact same code, but it works without error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['1996-09-27 00:00:00+10','1996-09-27 0000:00+11']})
df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: x[:-3])
```

Output df['col']:

> 0   1996-09-27 00:00:00
> 1   1996-09-27 0000:00

My guess is: maybe the type of `df['col']` is float instead of string? You could check it with `df['col'].dtypes`.